# flexbox one element fixed height, other filling

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I want to make some kind of image viewer with some descriptive text below. Problem is, that the lower box with the description has a fixed height and the image should fill the remaining height of whatever container it is in.

I wanted to use flexbox for that, as I think it seems to be the most elegant and simple solution (without using JS).
This this code and codepen for my current work, which seems to work mostly:

```
html,  body,  #container {
    height: 100%
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#container > #image {
/* flex-grow: 1; */ /* not needed here? */
    max-width: 75%;
    background-color: #fcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
     max-height: 100%;
    /* HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM STARTS!; */
     max-width: 100%;
}
#container > #text {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.7);
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 75%;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
/*  TOP MARGIN DOESN'T WORK */
}
```

http://codepen.io/Kageetai/pen/AaCJy

I got most of it to work but the image is not resizing itself correclty. As you can see through the transparent background of the text box, it stretches itself over the border of the containing div and even behind the text box.
So how can I retain the image with the correct aspect ratio inside its container?

And furthermore the centering with `margin: 0 auto;` seems to make problems when resizing the window. The image is not centered anymore and the page needs a refresh to make it work again.

So does anyone know how to make the image behave correctly? :)

Comment: I'm amazed this hadn't been upvoted before mine. Thanks for posting the question Kageetai :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For image , you can set an height, margin and display.

For image container, give a 2 or 3 value to flex and none to other, so it fills as much space as avalaible.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gasiy)**

CSS used :

```
html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container > #text {
  background-color: #ccf;
  padding: 5px;
}
#container>#image {
  flex:3;
  display:flex;
}
img {
  width:auto;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Chrome 36, I just saw it works in Firefox!
But is there a reason for the `display:flex;` on the image container?

Comment: ah :) , oki , for chrome we need to tell it more : check this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdtsC (flex-direction and min/height instead plain height . the reason is to trigger some flex peticularity else to access css rule that else would not be usable (max-height needs an height with a valid value to inherit usable reference, flex allow to ignore it #image has no heights in CSS , just a flex value ;) )

Comment: @Kageetai actually, FF needs to be filtered: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eJhnc ... but still fails for IE i believe

Comment: hey, thanks, that seems to work mostly, but I still notice a slight error in the aspect artio of the image. For example when I resize the codepen preview pane to the height, so that the image has the height of 600px (the original height), the width is at 972px with 900px being the original there.

Comment: Why does this work ONLY FOR GROWING the image – if the image has a bigger height than it would get in the container, it's not being resized: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmLGZq

Comment: To also **shrink** the image, it needs an explicit ```flex-basis: 10px``` (small enough), that sets the initial space it takes before (negative) space is distributed. Otherwise the image's physical dimensions are apparently the flex-basis.

Comment: Why ```flex-grow: 2``` or 3? These are magic numbers! Default for ```flex-grow``` is 0 anyway, so 1 would be not only sufficient, but the only logical value to set, no?

Comment: @Andy hello, 1 or more will do , it can matter if you have other items with flex values set too. the image shrinking expanding is a known bug with different issues through browsers.  hopefully this will be fixed one day, or least, all will have same behavior. CSS is in constant evolution ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more basic demo of how to achieve this.

```
<html style="height: 100%">
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0; display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <p>Toolbar</p>
    <div style="background: #bbb; flex: 1">Image</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A demo can be seen over at [Codepen](http://codepen.io/bjfletcher/pen/KdQeav).